# Kernel of homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is it possible to explain the sentence "the kernel of $\phi$, where $\phi: p(x,y) \mapsto a_0$  consists of all the polynomials with no constant term, is $<x,y>$  ".

How do we find the kernel? Any answer would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't have to *find* the kernel: it's already been given to you! Proving that it really is the kernel is possibly a much easier problem.

Comment: See the almost identical http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1021080/92067

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure. The kernel of $\phi: p(x,y) \mapsto a_{0}$ are the polynomials whose image is $0$ under $\phi$. Since $\phi(p(x,y))$ is the constant term of $p(x,y)$, it follows that $\ker \phi$ are the polynomials with no constant term. Now, we must show that this kernel is the ideal generated by $x$ and $y$, or $\langle x, y \rangle$. To do this, we show mutual containment. Suppose $p(x,y) \in \ker(\phi)$. Then every term of $p(x,y)$ is of the form $\alpha x^{i}y^{j}$ where at least one of $i, j$ is $> 0$. Hence, $p(x,y)$ is a finite sum of terms in $\langle x, y \rangle$, hence is in $\langle x, y \rangle$. This show the containment $\ker \phi \subset \langle x, y \rangle$. Can you show $\langle x, y \rangle \subset \ker \phi$? Feel free to comment if you need more hints!

Edit: a brief aside. First, while it may be obvious to you, I think that the kernel of $\phi$ might be more obvious if it were written a little differently. Really, $\phi$ is the *evaluation homomorphism* at the point $(0,0)$. Inuitively, then, the polynomials which are killed by this homomorphism are those with no constant term, since any powers of $x$ and $y$ are killed by plugging in $0$, leaving only the constant term.

Comment: *Let $p(x,y)\in\langle x,y\rangle$ then $p(x,y)=xg(x,h)+yh(x,y),g(x,y),h(x,y)\in\mathbb{C}[x,y]$

$\phi(p(x,y))=\phi(x)\phi(g(x,y))+\phi(y)\phi(h(x,y))=0 \Rightarrow p(x,y)\in ker\phi$

$\Rightarrow\langle x,y\rangle\subseteq ker\phi$
$$$$
*Let $p(x,y)\in ker\phi\Rightarrow\phi(p(x,y))=0$

$\ p(x,y)$ is of the form $ax^iy^j$ where at least one of $i,j$ is $>0$.

Hence, $p(x,y)$ is a finite sum of combinations of $x$ and $y$, hence $p(x,y)\in\langle x,y\rangle$

$\Rightarrow\langle x,y\rangle\supseteq ker\phi$

$$\Rightarrow ker\phi =\langle x,y\rangle$$
Is it correct? Can I improve something?

Comment: Your first part looks good. $p(x,y)$ is not of the form $ax^{i}y^{j}$ though; it's terms are. $p(x,y)$ is a finite sum of these terms. The argument looks fine otherwise.

Comment: @A Wertheim Why is p(x,y) a finite sum of these terms???

Comment: @user159870: it is a polynomial in $x$ and $y$. Therefore, it is a finite sum of terms (otherwise it would not be a polynomial), and its terms are of the form $\alpha x^{i}y^{j}$, where $i, j \geq 0$. Since $p(x,y)$ has no constant term, it follows that one of $i, j$ is always $\geq 1$. Does this clarify things?

Comment: Yes! Thank you!